# Can singleton contains disposable property?

Tags: c#, singleton, idisposable

I have interface as below:

```
public interface ISecretKeysStore
{
    Task<ECDiffieHellman> GetECDiffieHellman();
}
```

And it's implementation:

```
public class InMemorySecretKeysStore : ISecretKeysStore
{
    private readonly ECDiffieHellman _eCDiffieHellman;

    public InMemorySecretKeysStore(ECDiffieHellman eCDiffieHellman)
    {
        _eCDiffieHellman = eCDiffieHellman;
    }

    public Task<ECDiffieHellman> GetECDiffieHellman() => Task.FromResult(_eCDiffieHellman);
}
```

Singleton configuration:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISecretKeysStore>(new InMemorySecretKeysStore(eCDiffieHellman));
```

ECDiffieHellman is disposable. Is it safe to use a disposable object in a singleton? What if someone uses dispose on this object? Can I somehow block the use of dispose on this object?

Comment: It looks like not a good design to me. Personally, I will probably add a `using` block to any value, returned from `GetSmth()` if such a value is `IDisposable/IAsyncDisposable`. The solution may be to implement facade / wrapper without `IDisposable` support. Or to inject factory and return new instance every time if it is possible.

Comment: Where does `eCDiffieHellman` come from? Does anything else use that particular instance`? If the instance is unique, you can certainly dispose the instance when the singleton is disposed.

Comment: I think wrapper isn't good idea, because with this example implementation: https://pastebin.com/npRgGu4n I always can call `Wrapper.ECDiffieHellman.Dispose()`. Also I can't return new instance every time if it's possible, because I load ECDiffieHellman one time (on startup), from any location, e.g. from file, which can be changed or removed.

Comment: The wrapper shown is useless here as it does not hide `Dispose`. You need to fully wrap the internal instance and expose the API you need except the Dispose. Something like https://pastebin.com/1ff6QHZa This looks ugly, so I do not want to post this as the answer, but I do not know better solution here.